# How does a Serializer handle Posted JSON data?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My front-end (Angular2) is posting JSON to my Django Rest Framework backend. I am confused how my serializer should handle the JSON and extract the information. How can my `ContactFormSerializer` extract the JSON `data['userDetails']['email']`?

```
# Posted data example:

{
    "sessionID": "1",
    "created": "2/12/2016",
    "completed": false,
    "payment": {
        ...
    },
    "userDetails": {
        "userID": 1,
        "email": "foo@gmail.com",
        "location": "US"
    }
}

class ContactUsView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        serializer =  ContactFormSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


 class ContactFormSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    def save(self):
        # How can I grab the user email address from the JSON?

        # send email to us
```

Comment: Did you get any error at the time of saving data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a custom save method for ContactFormSerializer.
Maybe it will help

```
def save(self,validated_data):
    user_details = validated_data.pop('userDetails')
    model = Model.objects.create(
        userID = user_details['userID'],
        email = user_details['email'],
        location = user_details['location']
    )
    model.save()
```